# Lua SQLite3 Update value

Tags: sqlite, lua

I'm new here so I firstly like to say hello.

My problem is that I'm working on my game in Lua, when I want to update an value in my database it needs to be done dynamically (by the user) for example.

When the value in the database equals 1, the user may want to change that to 0 (when he sets the `bloom` off) .

I can do it hard coded by using:

```
for test in db:nrows("UPDATE test SET bloom = 1 WHERE bloom = 0") do
```

I would like to allow the users to change that value. But how can I do this?
I already have a placeholder for this which is

```
local bloom = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use placeholders, as you should with any queries based on user input to avoid passing data as commands (aka SQL injections).

```
local stmt = db:prepare[[
  UPDATE test SET bloom = ? WHERE bloom = ?
]]
stmt:bind(new_bloom, previous_bloom)
stmt:exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you know how to capture the value in your program from the user,  you can then build a string dynamically to pass to the SQL so for example

```
local sql = string.format([["UPDATE test SET bloom = 1 WHERE bloom = %s"]],bloom)
local res = assert(db:execute(sql))
```

I normally, use execute for update statements rather than nrows.

Comment: User, meet SQL injection. SQL injection, meet user.